# SHAP DeepExplainer Error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'device'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, time-series, shap

I am trying to to build an explainer for my multivariate time-series model (PyTorch) with SHAP as the following:

```
e = shap.DeepExplainer(
        model.to('cuda:1'), 
        torch.tensor(X_test_matrix,dtype=torch.float).to('cuda:1'))
```

Where X_test_matrix is a 3D matrix, since it is time-series data.
However, I receive an error like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-6aa8f8197e30> in <module>
      1 e = shap.DeepExplainer(
      2         model.to('cuda:1'),
----> 3         torch.tensor(X_test_matrix,dtype=torch.float).to('cuda:1'))

~/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/shap/explainers/_deep/__init__.py in __init__(self, model, data, session, learning_phase_flags)
     84             self.explainer = TFDeep(model, data, session, learning_phase_flags)
     85         elif framework == 'pytorch':
---> 86             self.explainer = PyTorchDeep(model, data)
     87 
     88         self.expected_value = self.explainer.expected_value

~/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/shap/explainers/_deep/deep_pytorch.py in __init__(self, model, data)
     55 
     56             # also get the device everything is running on
---> 57             self.device = outputs.device
     58             if outputs.shape[1] > 1:
     59                 self.multi_output = True

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'device'
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I imagine your model is outputting a tuple -- does this error happen when you output a single tensor?

Comment: @rvinas I don't think so but how can I verify that? Thanks!

Comment: @KaihuaHou could you show what the output of the model looks like? Either by adding `forward` method code or by printing inference example?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is due to the CUDA index.

Does this fix it for you?

```py
e = shap.DeepExplainer(
        model.to(torch.device('cuda')), torch.tensor(X_test_matrix, dtype=torch.float, device=torch.device('cuda'))
```

Comment: I tried it and it would return the following error: ```RuntimeError: Expected condition, x and y to be on the same device, but condition is on cuda:0 and x and y are on cuda:0 and cuda:1 respectively```

Comment: @KaihuaHou, can you show your inference code, what is `condition`? The error seems to occur because SHAP is running your code and encounters an error there.

Comment: @KaihuaHou where is `X_test_matrix` coming from? Seems like it is being stored on a different CUDA device than `model`